# How to route traffic from private LAN to specific public remote host via alternate gateway?

Tags: routing, nat, local-area-network, ip-routing

### Overview

I am trying to deal with the following scenario:

```
+------+                 (Internet)  50.a.b.c +---------+
| edge + eth0 <-----------------------------> + outpost |
+--+---+  25.u.v.w       (Secured by IPSec)   +---------+
   | enp                                      ^
   |  10.0.0.1                                |
   |                                          |
   | enp                                      |
   |  10.0.0.2                                |
+--+---+                                      |
| node + eth0 <----- XXX (FORBIDDEN) XXX -----+
+------+  160.r.s.t
```

There is an `edge` host with public IP `25.u.v.w` on interface `eth0` and a private IP `10.0.0.1` in LAN `10.0.0.0/24` on interface `enp`.

Likewise, there's a `node` host in the same LAN `10.0.0.0/24` which has a distinct public IP `160.r.s.t` on `eth0` and `10.0.0.2` for the LAN.

`edge` maintains an IPSec secured link between `edge` and `outpost`.

`outpost` is only reachable via public IP `50.a.b.c`. `outpost` **must never be reachable via internet**, only IPSec connections from `edge` (iptables on `outpost` ensure that constraint).

`node` is not the single node in the network, there is a multitude of them. I only depict one node to keep things simple (should work the same for all nodes).

All hosts run Ubuntu 22.04.

### Task

How can I make sure that `node` accesses `outpost` by routing its packets via `edge` over `enp` and then to `outpost` via `eth0`?

### About `edge`

#### Routing table of `edge`

With comments below

```
# ip r
default via 172.16.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 25.u.v.w metric 100
# Default route intended for unspecific internet access. 172.16.1.1 seems to be the VM bridge of the cloud service provider.
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.254 dev enp
# access to LAN via gateway
10.0.0.254 dev enp scope link
# no idea why this is needed
172.16.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 25.u.v.w metric 100
# Seems to define the next hop to the VM bridge gateway
```

#### Interfaces of `edge`

Only relevant entries shown:

```
# ip a
...
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 25.u.v.w/32 metric 100 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 57218sec preferred_lft 57218sec
    inet6 e:f:g:h::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9400:2ff:fea1:8068/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/32 brd 10.0.0.1 scope global dynamic enp
       valid_lft 86280sec preferred_lft 86280sec
    inet6 fe80::8400:ff:fe61:cc98/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### About `node`

#### Pristine routing table of `node`

The routing table before change attempt

```
# ip r
default via 172.16.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 160.r.s.t metric 100
# Default route intended for unspecific internet access. 172.16.1.1 seems to be the VM bridge of the cloud service provider.
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.254 dev enp
# access to LAN via gateway
10.0.0.254 dev enp scope link
# no idea why this is needed
172.16.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 160.r.s.t metric 100
# Seems to define the next hop to the VM bridge gateway
```

As you can see, `node` is configured equally to `edge` in that it route internet traffic via the default gateway (as intended).

#### Interfaces of `node`

```
# ip a
...
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 160.r.s.t/32 metric 100 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 55654sec preferred_lft 55654sec
    inet6 i:j:k:l::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9400:2ff:fea1:91a3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:00:00:61:d1:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.2/32 brd 10.0.0.2 scope global dynamic enp
       valid_lft 52529sec preferred_lft 52529sec
    inet6 fe80::8400:ff:fe61:d148/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### Attempt to route traffic to `outpost` from `node` over `edge`

I inserted a seemingly harmless rule into `node`'s routing table:

```bash
ip r a 50.a.b.c via 10.0.0.1 dev enp proto static onlink
```

For any traffic destined for outpost, send it to `edge`.  `edge`'s routing table will perform the actual routing to `outpost`.

However, this rule made `node` completely inaccessible from `edge` as well as its public IP `160.r.s.t`.

I don't understand why this rule affects *incoming* traffic. It should affect outgoing traffic targeted at `outpost`.

### Do I need SNAT Postrouting?

After doing some more research it seems I might need a rule on `edge` like

```bash
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 25.u.v.w
```

I haven't yet applied this rule as it does not resolve the actual issue of making `node` inaccessible on the routing table change denoted above.

### How would the correct routing table look like for `node`?

Referring to the task described above, how would a **proper** routing table for `node` look like?

Constraints:

- Access to `outpost` must be routed to `edge` (via LAN 10.0.0.0/24), from there NATed with public source IP `25.u.v.w` to `outpost`
- Access to any other internet host must go via the default gateway and use `node`'s public IP `160.r.s.t`.
- Access to nodes within LAN 10.0.0.0/24 must be routed locally.

Do I have to consider something else in order to make routing to `outpost` work?

Can someone with more networking experience shed light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the culprit. The `iptables` rules and routing table entries were essentially correct. However, the cloud-provider had an opaque gateway `10.0.0.254` in the private LAN.

I was missing an entry in the cloud-provider's web configuration that redirected all traffic from the opaque gateway `10.0.0.254` to `edge` on `10.0.0.1`.

Once I did that, the rule

```bash
ip r a 50.a.b.c via 10.0.0.1 dev enp proto static onlink
```

still made `node` immediately unreachable. One **still** had to funnel the traffic over the opaque gateway which redirected it back to `edge` somehow.

So the correct route was

```
ip r a 50.a.b.c via 10.0.0.254 dev enp proto static onlink
```

As this solution is cloud-provider specific and does not answer the actual question, I will not mark my own answer as a solution.